# How to add Poisson noise and Gaussian noise?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to add Gaussian and Poisson noise to an image.

I have been tried to implement this as follows but the result is not what I was expecting.

```
     I = imread('eight.tif');
     J = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0, 0.02); %mean variance
     figure, imshow(I), figure, imshow(J)
     P = imnoise(I,'poisson'); 
     figure, imshow(P)
     K = J+P;
     figure, imshow(K)
```

How do I correctly add Poisson noise and Gaussian noise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be applying `imnoise` to `J`, not to `I`.

```
 K = imnoise(J,'poisson');
 figure, imshow(K)
```

`imnoise` already **adds** the noise to your image, so adding `J+P` will add the image to itself, *in addition* to the already-added noise.

Comment: @gmotree If this fixes your problem, accept the answer by clicking on the ✓.