# How do I add some Gaussian noise to a tensor in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor I created using

```
    temp = torch.zeros(5, 10, 20, dtype=torch.float64)
    ## some values I set in temp
```

Now I want to add to each temp[i,j,k] a Gaussian noise (sampled from normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 0.1). How do I do it? I would expect there is a function to noise a tensor, but couldn't find anything. I did find this:

[How to add Poisson noise and Gaussian noise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823066/how-to-add-poisson-noise-and-gaussian-noise)

but it seems to be related to images.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The function `torch.randn` produces a tensor with elements drawn from a Gaussian distribution of zero mean and unit variance. Multiply by `sqrt(0.1)` to have the desired variance.

```
x = torch.zeros(5, 10, 20, dtype=torch.float64)
x = x + (0.1**0.5)*torch.randn(5, 10, 20)
```

Comment: Why do you multiply by `sqrt(0.1)` instead of just `0.1`?

Comment: Ah, the you use `sqrt(0.1)` because variance is standard deviation squared

Comment: A slight (more general) clarification, it's because if you have any random variable X with variance `v` and mean `m`, if you let `Y = kX` where `k` is a scalar, Y will have mean `km` but variance `k^2 v`. Since torch.randn is a normally distributed random variable (X with variance 1), if you want a variance of 0.1, you need to multiply by sqrt(0.1) so that the resulting variance will be `sqrt(0.1)^2 = 0.1`. Hope that's useful!